# mariaDB, Delete from multiple tables is really safe?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it really safe to delete from multiple tables conected by foreign key on mariaDB? Because according to mysql documentation, it is not!

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might process tables in an order that differs from that of their parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables to be modified accordingly.

But i can't find anything about this in mariaDB documentation! Besides, i see a lot of people saying that "it is ok"...

Comment: If you have this concern, then why not just run the `DELETE` statements in the order you want within a transaction?  You could also look into `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which might suit your needs.

Comment: i know that there are several ways to do this but i just wanted to know if this one is really safe...

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, then read carefully what your quote from the documentation says: `you should delete from a single table and rely on the ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides...` using `ON DELETE CASCADE` allows you to do similar things that a join delete could do, apparently without the risks which the latter has.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! i think that i understand it now!

Comment: Good.  But if you are using MyISAM then `ON DELETE CASCADE` would not be an option.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help! :D